# multiple instance of SLSQP optimizer not possible?

Tags: openmdao

I've got my problem set up using a collaborative optimization architecture. That is I have a component that wraps and runs its own optimization using SLSQP. This component is called by the higher level problem. It works well enough if I select COBYLA as the top level optimizer, but not SLSQP. From what I understand that's because the scipy optimizers are not re-entrant -- no multiple instances running simultaneously.

Is there any way around the problem, that is having two instances of the scipy SLSQP optimizer running independently in one problem? Was the Subproblem class in OpenMDAO 1.x designed to address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non reentrant nature of SLSQP can't really be worked around via any class structure tricks in the python layer. It's a problem with how the memory is allocated in the fortran layer, and ultimately you get down there no matter which object is calling it.

Here are some options:

1. use SLSQP at one level and COBYLA at another
2. modify SLSQP to be re-entrant
3. Try out IPOPT instead