Run two Dymos problems in tandem
My workflow using Dymos often involves running alot of Dymos optimisations in tandem so I can debug faster (i.e. I can try a bunch of different things at the same time). This has been working until recently. I am using the Spyder IDE and running each slightly different optimisation in its own console. Now, if I get one going in the first console (say (1/A)), open a new console and try to get another going, I get the following error:
> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'SLSQP.out'\

I am using the SLSQP driver but this was also the case previously, so I'm at a bit of a loss.
Thanks.

Scipy's SLSQP implementation is not re-entrant (it's not guaranteed that multiple running optimizations won't clash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64015874/multiple-instance-of-slsqp-optimizer-not-possible). I'd recommend using a different optimizer, such as IPOPT which is available through pyOptSparse when installed using conda: https://mdolab-pyoptsparse.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/install.html#conda

@JohnJasa I very much appreciate the very quick answer. Running the second optimisation w/ IPOPT seems to work for running in tandem. Beyond this advantage, are  there disadvantages to using IPOPT? I have confused myself trying to compare the different options in the past. If your answer is just that I should watch one of your videos that I have missed, that's aok by me (btw your videos are extremely helpful and  funny)

There aren't any meaningful disadvantages, just that SLSQP ships with Scipy and IPOPT comes through pyOptSparse (which might be more challenging to install on different systems). Thanks for the kind words, I'm glad you like the videos!

We're in the process of reworking the way OpenMDAO saves output files from executions, including the optimizer output files like SLSQP.out.
These are placed in a sub-directory based upon the name of the problem being executed. This information is currently saved in reports/{problem_name}, although we're going to be changing this in the future.
You can set the name of the problem in the instantiation.
So if you were instantiating your problems in a for loop, you could do something like:
for i in range(num_cases):
    p = om.Problem(name=f'case_{i}')
    ...

Or if you're just running multiple cases from a given script you could base the name of the case on some set of identifying characteristics of the case.  Regardless of how you do it, specifying unique problem names each time should resolve your error.
Just beware of disk space if you start naming these sequentially, you'll periodically need to clean up the output/report directories.

Thank you so much for your quick response! It's very appreciated. I have done this and it does create the appropriately named folder in the reports directory when trying to run the second optimisation. However, I get the same error about SLSQP.out. I have also looked and found that SLSQP.out is not contained in any reports subfolder. It may be relevant that I am working with Dymos 1.8.0.

Interesting, this is an OpenMDAO issue and there is currently an OpenMDAO pull request that should address this.  Hopefully we can finish testing it and get it merged in in the next few days.
Assuming SLSQP's output file is going into some top level folder, the current workaround would be to create a temporary directory for your problem and then change to that directory and execute your problem.  I'll add an issue so that we can test for this behavior and make sure it stays resolved when we get it fixed.

Thanks Rob. I looked around and can confirm that the SLSQP.out file is in the directory of the main script (the one that sets up the problem, calls the ODE, etc.)
